# How to Restricting one like per post in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am a beginner in `Django` currently. **I want to restrict one like per post in my so Posting kind of app**, where you can post a text and user can like or dislike the same. Now I enabled Login and I want a logged in user to like a post only once and I am unsuccessful in doing so.

**Models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.

class Todo(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    like=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

**Views,py**

```
def like(request,todo_id):
    if Todo.objects.filter(todo_id = todo_id, user_id=request.user.id).exists():
        return redirect('index')
    else:
        todo = Todo.objects.get(pk=todo_id)
        todo.like += 1
        todo.save()
        return redirect('index')
```

Comment: Have you considered maybe creating another model in which you will have Todo and User models as FKs? That way you can track which user liked which Todo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What basically I was missing is saving the likes corresponding to user. And this problem is easily solved by creating a model with User and main model as Foreign Key's as pointed out by Paolo.

**models.py**

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Todo(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text

class Todo_likes(models.Model):
    todo = models.ForeignKey(Todo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**views.py**

```py
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from .models import Todo,Todo_likes
from .forms import TodoForm

def like(request,todo_id):
    user = request.user
    todo = Todo.objects.get(id=todo_id)
    like, created = Todo_likes.objects.get_or_create(   # get_or_create will 
                                                        # itself do the job of 
                                                        # finding and creating if not exist
        user = user,
        todo = todo
    )
    if not created:
        return redirect('index') #I don't wanted to show any error if existed earlier.
                                 #I just wanted to redirect.

    else:
        return redirect('index')
```

And then counting my number of likes by simply going to my Index view and inserted

```py
def index(request):
    form = TodoForm()
    todo_list = Todo.objects.order_by('id')
    likes = Todo_likes.objects.count()  # Adding this line
    context= {'todo' : todo_list, 'form':form, 'likes' : likes} 
    return render(request,'todolistapp/index.html',context)
```

And displaying 'likes' object in my template.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to give it a try and expand on my comment.

My suggestion is, to create a new model `Todo_Likes` which will have both `Todo` and `User` model as `Foreign Keys` to be able to track who liked a `Todo`.

***models.py***

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.

class Todo(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    # Got rid of the user FK and like since I would count likes using
    # Todo_Like.objects.count()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text

class Todo_Like(models.Model):
    todo = models.ForeignKey(Todo)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

***views.py***

```
def like(request,todo_id):
    # Get user
    user = request.user
    # Get Todo object
    todo = Todo.objects.get(id=todo_id)

    # Check/Validate if current user has already liked the Todo. 
    # If not create a new Todo_Like object.

    todo_like = Todo_Like.objects.get(todo=todo, user=user)

    if not todo_like:
        # If the user haven't like the Todo object yet create a Todo_Like object.
        t = Todo_Like (
            todo=todo,
            user=user
            )
        t.save()
    else:
        # If the user has already liked the Todo then proceed to do
        # Whatever you want, redirect? message?
```

I would also like to answer a question in advance.

1. You might ask **how would you count the likes now?** Answer: Make use of Todo_Like.objects.count(), and make sure you count it by Todo.

Comment: Well thanks @Paolo I created a Todo_Likes model, but I tried your views.py and it didn't worked for me. But I am able to make it work and posting my code here. Thanks again!